# C++ Variable Width Bit Field

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I'm writing a program that is supposed to manipulate very long strings of boolean values. I was originally storing them as a dynamic array of `unsigned long long int` variables and running C-style bitwise operations on them.

However, I don't want the overhead that comes with having to iterate over an array even if the processor is doing it at the machine code level - i.e. it is my belief that the compiler is probably more efficient than I am.

So, I'm wondering if there's a way to store them as a bitfield. The only problem with that is that I heard you needed to declare a constant at runtime for that to work and I don't particularly care to do that as I don't know how many bits I need when the program starts. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at `std::bitset` ?

Comment: Or perhaps `std::vector<bool>`, depending on how you are going to "manipulate" them.

Comment: And Boost has `dynamic_bitset`. Bitfields won't work; they do have to be constant width (and no bigger than a normal integral type, I think).

Comment: Exactly what "manipulation" are we talking of?

Comment: I hadn't heard of `std::bitset` I'll look into it. I'd rather not use `std::vector<bool>` as there could be in excess of a million bits and I don't want to allocate a byte to each one. I'd rather not use Boost if I can get away with it. As for manipulation, I'm talking about the usual C-style bitwise operators, <<, >>, |, &, ^, ~, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>` are probably what you need. `bitset` is fixed-length, `vector<bool>` is dynamic.

`vector<bool>` is a specialization of vector that only uses one bit per value, rather than `sizeof(bool)`, like you might expect... While good for memory use, this exception is actually disliked by the standards body these days, because (among other things) `vector<bool>` doesn't fulfil the same contract that `vector<T>` does - it returns proxy objects instead of references, which wreaks havoc in generic code.